# Windows IIS displaying SSL certificate, but generating 404 error

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, amazon-ami

I've got a bit of a strange situation. I've got an Amazon EC2 with Windows Server 2012 running Coldfusion with IIS.

The strange issue is my server is appearing to match the domain to the server with the SSL certificate on the box.

The site's content however is generating a 404 error for no matter what I do to it.

This might be considered quite vague, but what I'm wondering is, is this a common fault? That being the SSL cert gets processed to the browser but all content fails?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

An SSL Certificate has nothing to do with a `404` error.

`404 Not Found` error code stands for :

> The requested resource could not be found but may be available again
>   in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

I suspect you are serving the wrong `wwwroot` directory in your IIS Website config.
The directory you serve does not contains the files/folders you are requested.